# Spring Cloud Gateway accessing Principal

Tags: spring-webflux, spring-cloud-gateway

This question relates to my lack of understanding of webflux...

When creating a global Spring Cloud Gateway filter e.g.

```
public class MyGlobalFilter implements GlobalFilter {

@Override
public Mono<Void> filter(ServerWebExchange exchange, GatewayFilterChain chain) {
  
  METHOD BODY

  return chain.filter(exchange);
}
```

The method exchange.getPrincipal() returns a Mono so accessing (I believe) needs to be done as part of a call chain.

How can I access the principal in the method body?

I have tried

```
exchange.getPrincipal().map(...).subscribe()
```

but that does not trigger.

I know I can successfully access the principal as a post action by doing the following.

```
return filter.chain(exchange).then(exchange.getPrincipal()).map(...)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the principal in the method body like this:

```java
@Override
public Mono<Void> filter(ServerWebExchange exchange, GatewayFilterChain chain) {
    return exchange.getPrincipal()
            .flatMap(principal -> {
                log.info("Principal {}", principal.getName());
                return chain.filter(exchange);
            });
}
```

---

To deal with the case when the `Mono` returned from `getPrincipal` method is empty, you would need to do something like this:

- The code below contains a simple example demonstrating the case of whether to continue the filter chain or not.
- Wrapping the `Principal` value to `Optional` (or `Optional.empty` in case of empty `Mono`) is used because `Mono<Void>` returned from later called method `chain.filter` completes without any value. So if we used `switchIfEmpty` it would be still called even if there was a value of `Principal`.

```java
@Override
public Mono<Void> filter(ServerWebExchange exchange, GatewayFilterChain chain) {
    return exchange.getPrincipal()
            .map(Optional::of)
            .defaultIfEmpty(Optional.empty())
            .flatMap(principal -> principal
                    .filter(this::isAuthorized)
                    .map(p -> chain.filter(exchange))
                    .orElseGet(() -> {
                        exchange.getResponse().setStatusCode(HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN);
                        return exchange.getResponse().setComplete();
                    }));
}

private boolean isAuthorized(Principal principal) {
    // Just an example
    return true;
}
```